# convert Excel glossary

Tags: 2011

I'm a beginner with this cat. I'd like to use my glossaries in Excel format. Where and How can I convert them. I have TRADOS 2015 and Multi-Term. But I cannot find the program to convert or import these excel files. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to the community. To get the proper answer please share details  as to what you are trying to achieve and what have you tried till now? Also, question is not very clear.

Comment: It doesn't look like this question is related to SDL's Web Content Management... maybe you should ask it on https://community.sdl.com/solutions/language/translationproductivity instead?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's relating to SDL's Translation products.

Answer (score 3):

You are in the wrong place.  Tridion is not a CAT.  You can convert your files using MultiTerm Convert, or the Glossary Converter, but the best place to ask is in the SDL Community as suggested earlier.  If you use http://xl8.one it'll take you to the right group to post in.